# React - avoid re-rendering an object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an auction object and for the sake of the argument let's say this object contains only 2 properties; remainingTime and amount. I have set up a countdown timer (I used react-countdown-now library) for the remainingTime, I also have a button to make an offer, when this button is clicked an offered is added with the amount equal to current amount + 100.

All this works, the problem is that whenever I click the offer button React re-renders the whole component and that resets my timer and I don't want that. How can I tell React to not re-render the remainingTime property?

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/x27j7kqxrq

Comment: share your code, then we would be able to help you.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: The problem is not on component re-render but the state data that you clone each time a button is clicked. Those datas rewind timer to initial state. You should return each click the current time remaining to override the one contained in your parent state

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Create subcomponents. If you create a subcomponent for each part, the timer and the amount, then you can render updates to the amount without affecting the timer and wrap those into your application state, instead of the object containing the two.

Comment: Umm this might work, I'll see how I can implement this logic while rendering a list of the auction objects.